# Need to create a copy of a Database to a location not under Data

Tags: database, copy, lotus-domino

I want to create a copy of a database to a folder not under the data either locally or on a server I have code that looks like this:

```
var arcName:String = "C:\Archive\MyArchives\SomeName.nsf"
var arcDB:NotesDatabase = appDB.createCopy("", arcName);
```

When the action finishes (it does not generate any errors) I can't find the database anywhere. if I change the arcName to "Archives\Myarchives\SomeName,nsf" the process works correctly. But I don't want these Archives under Data.

Using the full path does not seem to make it move out from under the Data folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be a case of string escaping - in SSJS, like most C-lineage languages, `\` is the escape character. Give it a shot with `\\` in place of each. In my testing, it works as `database.createCopy("", "C:\\Archive\\MyArchives\\SomeName.nsf")`.

Comment: Thanks - it seems to work OK when the out put is to the server but the local copy seems to get lost. I will try your suggestion.

Comment: Very strange it works with either the "\" or the "\\" in the arcName if the output is to the server, but when out put is to local it appears to work but I can not locate the files on my local machine. Really confusing. Will need to investigate further.